# Activating tab through URL while using Bootstrap and Slim framework with Twig extension

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, slim, twig-extension

I'm using `slim framework` with `twig extension` and `bootstrap` to render a page with multiple nested tabs.
Is there a method to activate certain tab through URL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow1 Could you please edit your post and add details to make your question more specific?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working with my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

In your container method that creates the twig extensions, you can add the following to make a `current_uri` object available in your twig views:

```php
$view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('current_uri', $container['request']->getUri();
```

Then, in your view you can write a twig condition to check if the page is active:

```
<a class="{{ current_uri.path == 'tab1' ? 'active' : '' }}">Tab 1</a>
<a class="{{ current_uri.path == 'tab1' ? 'active' : '' }}">Tab 1</a>
```